# How do I set a validation error on a component inside a composite component?

Tags: 8, webforms

I have a webform with a composite component that allows multiple rows to be added. The structure is something like this, in case that makes it clearer:

```
webform
  sample_details - composite component which allows multiple 'rows', containing:
    sample_ref 
    date_sampled (field I want to set the error on)
```

I followed 'method 2 - webform handler' on [this guide](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/webform/webform-cookbook/how-to-add-custom-validation-to-a-webform-element#s-method-2-using-webform-handlers). I'm able to do the validation itself and set an error on other components, but not on sub-components in the composite one.

[This post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/243994/how-to-set-validation-error-for-specific-subfield-of-the-paragraph-type) addresses a similar problem, but the technique hasn't helped me.

I've tried

```
$form_state->setErrorByName( 'date_sampled', $this->t( 'must not have a sample date in the future.' ) );
```

and

```
$form_state->setErrorByName( 'sample_details][date_sampled]', $this->t( 'must not have a sample date in the future.' ) );
```

and a few other things but it seems like I'm missing something. It seems that `setErrorByName` can't work on sub-components because they don't have a standard `#parents` array? Is there a way of achieving this without having to switch to 'the old way'?

Answer (score 1):

The element name "sample_details][date_sampled]" specified in the first parameter of setByErrorName is not correct.

It should be

```
// $key = your multi field array key eg 0,1,2,3 
$formState->setErrorByName('sample_details][items][' . $key . '][_item_][date_sampled', $this->t('must not have a sample date in the future.'));
```

You can find out the exact element name by two methods:

1. `$formState->getUserInput()` will give you the exact array pattern to use for setting error by name.
2. Inspect the element from the browser and use the value of `name attribute`.